# Can an app register with the system for BLE Device notifications in Android SDK 21?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ibeacon

An iOS App registers a BLE Device in the system and the system informs the App, if this device is found.

An Android App has to scan on its own. In Android SDK 21 there is a new BLE scan API, but there is no way to register a BLE Device and have the system inform the app.

Is that correct and why doesn't Google support it?

Comment: Just to clarify, on the iOS side are you referring to the `UIBackgroundModes` options for peripheral scanning or the peripheral connection alert options, such as `CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnConnectionKey`?